# erdos.sdslabs problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be the largest positive integer, such that $n!$ can be expressed as the product of $(n−2014^{2015})$ consecutive integers.

Let $x$ be equal to $n$ mod $38980715857$. Find x mod $8037517$ ?

Question source is [this](https://erdos.sdslabs.co/problems/74).
.

Answer (score 0):

as we know that value of n is equal to(by solving it with number theory)
n=(2014^2015!)+1
now,
given that x=n mod38980715857.
by solving it with help of wolfram alpha we get,
x=38980715856,
further xmod8037517is equal to:
6795923